# Exibir uma label enquanto que a página está a carregar

Tags: javascript

Estou a tentar criar uma `label`, que aparece enquanto que a página está a carregar, com um `"a carregar"`.

E assim que a página estiver toda carregada, esconder a `label`.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
document.getElementById("lblmsg").innerHTML = "carregar...";

for(var i=1; i>1000; i++){
  var value = i*i*i*i;
}

function callFunction(){
  document.getElementById("lblmsg").style.display = 'none';

}
```

e o HTML:

```
<body onload="callFunction();">
  <label id="lblmsg"></label>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Se você precisa somente "esconder" o conteúdo do site antes do **`load`** ser disparado, pode usar uma classe com essa propriedade que está inserindo diretamente no DOM, fica mais fácil a manipulação:

```
.hide { display: none }
```

O conteúdo a ser "escondido" enquanto a página é carregada pode inicialmente possuir essa classe. Bastando então removê-la quando o **`load`** for disparado.

<sub>**ps:** Coloquei uma imagem para o 'load' demorar a ser disparado em um primeiro carregamento.</sub>

```js
var loading = document.querySelector('div'),
    content = document.querySelector('main');

window.onload = function() {
  loading.classList.add('hide');    // esconde o 'carregando'.
  content.classList.remove('hide'); // mostra o conteúdo do site.
};
```

```css
.hide, img { display: none }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>carregando...</p>
</div>

<main class='hide'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoKIw.jpg' />
  conteúdo do site.
</main>
```

No exemplo acima utilizei [**`classList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) mas já adianto que nem todos os navegadores possuem esse recurso implementado. Internet Explorer < 10 e Opera Mini 5 não dão suporte ao `classList` - [*ver navegadores que suportam*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). De qualquer forma [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8098406/4056678)<sup><sup>(en)</sup></sup> existem possíveis soluções que você pode utilizar.

---

Se quer exibir uma barra de progresso conforme o site é carregado (mostrando a porcentagem), sugiro utilizar o [PACE](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) para isto.

Answer (score 2):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
<body>
  <label id="lblmsg">Carregando...</label>
 </body>

<script>
window.onload = callFunction;
</script>
```

Nesse caso, `window.onload` faz com que essa função seja executada depois de toda a página ser carregada.

É melhorar deixar a codificação toda numa tag `script` ou em um `arquivo javascript`. Fica mais fácil de dar manutenção no código.

E creio que nesse caso, a melhor escolha é da deixar a palavra `Carregando...` dentro da `label#lblmsg` e, então, quando o conteúdo estiver carregado, ocultá-la.